# Object in Vuetify select

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to submit to the server the ID of the selected fixtures but I don't know how.
I have to display an object (that I'm passing in props) in a select menu.

In my select menu I have:

```
 v-select
    v-model="form.array"
    :items="array"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="id"
    label="Select"
    outlined
    dense
    multiple
    chips
    return-object
 ></v-select>
```

and My form is

```
data() {

            return {
                form: Object.assign({}, defaultForm),
                valid: true,
                defaultForm,
                dialog: null,
                counterOfUnnamed: '',
                checkbox: true,
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with array of objects selected fixtures, also another question. Are you using lodash library

Comment: I don,t use lodsah

Comment: I update the object too

Comment: Okie i have given answer in javascript, use return object, you can have full object in array, thats not a problem

Comment: have you deleted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58505915/display-on-a-two-dimensional-array, I'm workiing on that solution and made it worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the fixtures first and then filter the id property from the filtered array

Here is the working code, it works perfectly

```
var self = this;
self.fixtures.filter(fixture => self.form.selectedFixture.map(x => x.id).includes(fixture.id)).map(fixture => fixture.id)
```

In your code add this inside your submit function, dont rewrite the existing this.form.selectedFixture, just craete a new variable assign to it and use then

```
submit() {
    var self = this;
    const selectedFixture = self.fixtures.filter(fixture => self.form.selectedFixture.map(x => x.id).includes(fixture.id)).map(fixture => fixture.id);
                   console.log(selectedFixture);
                    http.post('group/create', {
                        name: this.form.groupName,
                        fixtures: selectedFixture
                    }).then(result => {
                        this.groups.push(result);
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log((error));
                    });
                    this.resetForm();
                },
```

Comment: Where I need to filter , in the submit function ?

Comment: Added this inside submit function

Comment: Use filter instead of map , then at the end use map to select only id's

Comment: when I console.log(selectedFixture) I have the entire object, I just need an array of Ids, weird

Comment: Check now, it is fixed

Comment: I think now you are getting only array of ids,

Comment: I have another question to you , How can I display the name the selected fixtures ?

Comment: Just add name in the map at the end    self.fixtures.filter(fixture => self.form.selectedFixture.map(x => x.id).includes(fixture.id)).map(fixture => fixture.name)

Comment: no it's not to send to server , it's just to display in page for client, it's before the submit

Comment: If you want to display names in UI after select, just add a computed property or watcher and use this self.fixtures.filter(fixture => self.form.selectedFixture.map(x => x.id).includes(fixture.id)).map(fixture => fixture.name).toString()

Comment: Do accept and upvote this answer, if it resolve your issue, Thanks

Comment: And do I return something to display ?

Comment: For showing in UI <div v-if="form.selectedFixture.length">{{ formattedFixture }}</div>

computed: {
 formattedFixture() {
  return this.form.selectedFixture.map(x => x.name).toString()
 }
}

Comment: @Sébastian, here is the codepen for 2 d array loop https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/rNNjbOe?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Try create a question and share the question link, I can explain the code there. It can help others in understanding